# Chrome developers tool - autocomplete and argument hints in snippets tab under sources tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In console tab, I can see that autocomplete and argument hints work fine as shown below. How do I get this feature in snippets tab under sources tab?
This would help me type in javascript code quickly in javascript snippet file.

[image]

Comment: You don't edit in the Sources tab.

Comment: @ScottMarcus By default, no, but on the right panel there's a tab: "Snippets", and on it, you can create and EDIT your own scripts.

Comment: @JyotiPrasadPal I don't know why, but in snippets tab the autocomplete only works with variables, functions that you declared in the snippet